# Why there is a limitation of 2GB redis.io database on 32 bit machine

Tags: redis

Why there is a limitation of 2GB redis.io database for 32 bit machine; How can I overcome that limitation under 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

32 bit systems can't handle addresses greater than 2^32. That is 4GB, though the available memory for an individual process is obviously going to be lower than that.

The recommended approach is to split your data across multiple smaller redis instances.

This can even make sense on a 64 bit machine, since redis requires significantly less memory if it can use 32 instead of 64 bits for internal addressing.